# Can we create hashmap key singleton?

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, concurrenthashmap, linkedhashmap

I was giving interview one other day and i was speechless when questioning is done on hashmap
Here are few

Can we make key as singleton?

Can we make key of hashmap mutable or immutable  which one you will choose and why?

For second question i searched through web and found that if we are creating key it should be immutable otherwise data saved on first key and then modified later and if we try to get it again it will give null thus object will be lost.
Here is the link that i followed for this [Custom Key Hashmap](https://dzone.com/articles/things-to-keep-in-mind-while-using-custom-classes)

What about the first question Can we create Hashmap key singleton, according to me if we create key singleton then we lose power of hashmap using same key will replace data if we try to add using singleton key.

Please throw some light on it.

Comment: Honestly, I don’t understand the “Can we make key as singleton?” question. What does it mean?

Comment: @Holger if keys values are produced via singleton pattern.

Comment: If key is produced via singleton then of course only one (key,value) pair can be present in the map as (key,value) pairs must be distinguishable through keys (key is a **key**).

Comment: There is no relationship between a `HashMap` and the class design of objects used for the keys. And, no, this doesn’t affect what the `HashMap` can store either. See, `HashMap<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<>(); map.put(Runtime.getRuntime(), ""); map.put(FileSystem.getDefault(), 42);`, I have stored two singletons as keys…

Comment: @Holger I'm not sure that was the question, but at least that could be a good answer in some interview!

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès that’s the problem with the question; it’s not clear what it is about…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hmm, That's interesting.

First the Singleton Class in Java, is a class that can have only one object (an instance of the class) at a time.
that means only one copy shared between multiple Objects.

We have two objects of Singleton class

```
Singleton x = Singleton.getInstance(); 
Singleton y = Singleton.getInstance();
```

Scenario 1 : If we create HashMap with Singleton key then

```
Map<SingletonClass, Interger> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(x, 10);
        map.put(y, 20);
```

What do you think the output will be, 
          size would be 1 in this case and 10 is override by 20. Right?
Same object have same HashCode and equals method implementation.

Scenario 2 : what If one objectjust change the field's value of Singleton class

```
Map<SingletonClass, Interger> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(x, 10);
    y.s = (y.s).toUpperCase(); // s is a String field in Singleton Class
    map.put(y, 20);
```

in this case size would be 1. same hashcode for x and y.

So, there is always 1 object it will override the value again and again.

And as you know why we use Immutable class as a key. It's now clear that you can't use the Singleton class in a HashMap as a key.

Even If you override the HashCode Object as a key is stored as a reference in Map. So If you change its implementation it's get reflected in the Map while executing the hashcode method of Singleton Class.
Yes you can Override the equals method but it will increase the collision cases in HashMap only.

Answer (score 1):

A very interesting question as it necessitate to understand what exacatly are maps...

> 1. Can we make key as singleton?

If you use a singleton pattern to produce keys then obviously only one key will be created and then only one pair *(key,value)* will be present at a time in the map. This said, we obviously change the value associated to the sole possible key. This answer must be yes of course, the very nature of key is of no importance for the maps, but this will lead to a stupid or not very useful map (at least provide me a convincing example).

> 2. Can we make key of hashmap mutable or immutable which one you will
>      choose and why?

Chose immutable! If not you will have serious problems depending on the concrete map you chose.

For `HashMap` and alike:

```
import java.util.*;

class K {
  private int value;
  public boolean equals(Object o) { K k = (K)o; return k.value==value; }
  public int hashCode() { return value; }
  public K(int v) { this.value = v; }
  public void setValue(int v) { this.value = v; }
  public String toString() { return ""+value; }
}

public class Test {
  public static void main(String []a) {
    HashMap<K,String> m = new HashMap<K,String>();
    K k1 = new K(33);
    m.put(k1,"Here I am");
    K k2 = new K(44);
    m.put(k2,"Here it is");
    System.out.println("k1: "+k1+" "+m.get(k1));
    System.out.println("k2: "+k2+" "+m.get(k2));
    k1.setValue(666);
    System.out.println("k1: "+k1+" "+m.get(k1));

    k1.setValue(44);
    System.out.println("k2: "+k2+" "+m.get(k2));
    k1.setValue(666);
    System.out.println("k1: "+k1+" "+m.get(k1));
    k1.setValue(33);
    System.out.println("k1: "+k1+" "+m.get(k1));
  }
}
```

will produce:

```
k1: 33 Here I am
k2: 44 Here it is
k1: 666 null
k2: 44 Here it is
k1: 666 null
k1: 33 Here I am
```

which is naturally understandable as, the value inside the object key is used as the key for the map.

Now with `TreeMap` things are different:

```
import java.util.*;

class K implements Comparable<K> {
  private int value;
  public boolean equals(Object o) { K k = (K)o; return k.value==value; }
  public int hashCode() { return value; }
  public K(int v) { this.value = v; }
  public void setValue(int v) { this.value = v; }
  public String toString() { return ""+value; }
  public int compareTo(K k) { return Integer.compare(value,k.value); }
}

public class Test2 {
  public static void main(String []a) {
    TreeMap<K,String> m = new TreeMap<K,String>();
    K k1 = new K(33);
    m.put(k1,"Here I am");
    K k2 = new K(44);
    m.put(k2,"Here it is");
    System.out.println("k1: "+k1+" "+m.get(k1));
    System.out.println("k2: "+k2+" "+m.get(k2));
    k1.setValue(666);
    System.out.println("k1: "+k1+" "+m.get(k1));

    k1.setValue(44);
    System.out.println("k2: "+k2+" "+m.get(k2));
    k1.setValue(666);
    System.out.println("k1: "+k1+" "+m.get(k1));
    k1.setValue(33);
    System.out.println("k1: "+k1+" "+m.get(k1));
  }
}
```

will produce:

```
k1: 33 Here I am
k2: 44 Here it is
k1: 666 Here I am
k2: 44 Here I am
k1: 666 Here I am
k1: 33 Here I am
```

See how k2 and value 44 now access different values in the map... `k2` didn't mutate but values retrieved are not the same over time!

Thus, never use mutable keys...

Comment: your last line is little bit confusing whether to use immutable or not?